# I'm getting an error message when i try to power on a virtual machine

Tags: centos, centos7, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware 14. when i try to power on a virtual machine i am getting the following error message.

```
VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.
The VMX process exited prematurely.
```

I have installed 2 virtual machines. CentOs and fedora. fedora works fine. this issue comes with CentOs virtual machine. i tried running the VMware as admin. and i tried stopping all the VMware services and starting them back again. nothing seems to work. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if this is the permanent fix for this issue or not! but i kept on restarting the host machine for like 2-5 times and eventually the vm started working without any issue. but sometimes after i shutdown and power up the vm again the issue was still there. and restarting the host seems to fix this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and none of the online solutions worked for me. I just have to kill all VMWare app processes from the Task Manager and Stop all VMWare services (from Task Manager or Click Start type services and hit enter) and then start all the VMWare services, and Virtual Machine started fine. In my case there were some pending updates that might have caused this issue and as soon as I started the VM, the updates got installed.